# Access windows file system from linux shell script

Tags: linux, windows, shell-scripting

I want to know, whether is it possible to access the Windows files from a shell script on Linux system ?
What i am trying to do is to run a shell script in my Linux system, that will access the files of a remote Windows system, read them and manipulate them.
Forget about the file and folder permissions.

Is it possible to do this using the Linux shell scripts (or perl scripts)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can mount a windows share into the linux filesystem using [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) e.g.

```
mkdir /mnt/windowsfs
mount -t cifs //server/share -o username=user,password=P4ssw0rd /mnt/windowsfs
```

Once you've done that you can (with suitable permissions) access and manipulate the files in /mnt/windowsfs.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting the remote share is the most direct approach. However, there's also the [`smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html) executable, that gives FTP-like access to remote shares. It's a part of the [Samba software package](https://www.samba.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Install this command on linux

```
 sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

and

```
mkdir /mnt/windowsfs

sudo mount.cifs //WindowsPC/Share /mnt/windowsfs -o user=geek
```

its ask for password, enter password 
then check your /mnt/windowsfs folder...its Done.